# how to post data to another file in php

Tags: php, mysql

need a help in this regard
1. I need  to design a user input form which has three text fields say T1, T2, T3.
2. Now the inpust from these three should be packed into encode_json
3.I have a table with multiple rows, with auto increment id  1,2,3,4 so on. Now the same encoded json message should be passed onto a file send_message.php along with id and encoded json message.
here is the send_message.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["regId"]) && isset($_GET["message"])) {
    $regId = $_GET["regId"];
    $message = $_GET["message"];

    include_once './GCM.php';

    $gcm = new GCM();

    $registatoin_ids = array($regId);
    $message = array("price" => $message);

    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

    echo $result;
}
?>
```

For table related looping and count of rows you may use the following

```
if ($no_of_users > 0) {
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [cURL](http://php.net/curl) is the thing you're looking for.
For every row you could open a connection to `send_message.php` and pass the data you want.

Otherwise you could just include the `send_message.php`, but I would not recomment that.

**EDIT**
As you request, here is a **VERY BASIC** example:

```
<?php
$curlPostfields = array(
    'field1'=>$value1,
    'field2'=>$value2,
);

$curlHandler = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_URL, 'send_message.php');
curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPostfields);
curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curlHandler);
```

You could pack this in an own function and just call this function for every row of your table.

Comment: could you help me out with input text data creation and passing message code of php..as im new to it.thanks

Comment: It shows unexpected T_echo in the postdata function call line here is the code


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
                    postData( echo $row["id"]; , echo json_encode($data);)    
                    }

Comment: Don't use `echo` in this case. Just `postData($row['id'], json_encode($data));`.

Comment: thanks for it, still facing the issue while calling the function, it says postData function not found
<form method="post" >
            <input name="go" type="submit" value="Add New" />
            </form>
            <?php if(isset($_POST['go'])) { 

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($users)) {
                    postData($row["id"],json_encode($data));    
                    }
} 


}

  ?>  
postData is the method that you have mentioned earlier

Comment: Have do declared your `postData()` method? If yes, please show how.